# Dropdown Menu Anywhere with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a few links (they don't have to be a menu) all over the site. I need to have a dropdown block under some of them. Something like [Anylink](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/dropmenuindex.htm) Dropdown as show on Dynamic Drive. I need to be able to place dropdowns directly under any link I want with ease. How can I achieve this with jquery?

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $('#trigger').click( function(event){

    event.stopPropagation();

    $('#drop').slideToggle('fast');

  });

});​
```

I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wolverene/72wPP/2/)

Comment: Come on guys. please don't ban me from posting. I fixed the question already.

Comment: Thanks @undefined. I need to put a dropdown block (can contain a menu or html) directly under any link I want on a page. not so good with javascript and jquery but I try. please see my fiddle if it helps in anyway.

Comment: So is should be based on the position of element on the page, like a tooltip? If yes, you can try using jQuery offset method and absolute positioning.

Comment: Yes, exactly like how a tooltip positions itself based on the trigger element. can you show me a sample code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery UI menu

http://jqueryui.com/menu/

Thanks

Jng

Comment: This is very good. Although I need something quicker without having to bulk of jqueryui. I can use this one though for related stuff. Thanks.